# how to increase output current (5V Output, 1.5V input Switch Boost Converter)

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, boost

I designed a small boost converter with discrete  transistors, and now I need to increase the output current. The output is 30ma/5V but I need more than 70ma.
How can I improve the circuit?
R5 is load.

[image: dc-dc-converter]

Comment: If you designed it then you should know the circuit better than we do. So you should already know what is limiting the output current. You might just be expecting too much from this circuit. The input voltage of only 1.5 V and 5 V output means you're quickly running into all kinds of limitations. Go find a "state of the art" boost converter chip, check it's datasheet and see if it can do 5 V. 70 mA with only 1.5 V at the input.

Comment: What is the load, because it can't just be a 10K resistor for 70mA at 5V?

Comment: 1.5A is definitely more than 70mA, but hard to expect if you only have 30mA from a 1.5V source.  Or is that a typo?

Comment: @finbarr it use for a module, but i simulated with resistor so if i change R5 with 100R resistor , the output voltage decries to 1.5V. if I increase L1 and L2 It can improve but I looking for best way.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat  so sorry i change the 1.5A to 1.5 volt, I need 70ma/5V  and The battery should have a capacity of at least 250ma/1.5V, regardless of losses.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  I don't have expropriate about boost converter  calculation so i use my basic knowledge. please help me about calculation of parameter Ip,C,L and frequency

Comment: Stop thinking that you can just "do the calculation, adjust some component values and the circuit will work as expected". General boost converter formulas only apply to circuits where the components aren't "working on the edge" which is the case in this circuit. So all kinds of series resistances need to be taken into account for this circuit. That results in very complex formulas.

Comment: As @Bimpelrekkie says, calculations will only get you in the ballpark.  You will have to tweak the components  to get where you want.

Comment: Before the formulas "will work" you would need to solve: 1) the series resistance of the battery, battery contacts, wires to the circuit 2) address the switching losses of the transistors, your circuit is quite simple, switching on/off isn't done abruptly enough and the on resistance of the transistors will never be low enough. 3) you would need components that don't exist like low Vt MOSFETs with a very low Rdson. I'll make an analogy: your design is that of a Ford model-T but you're asking that to perform like a Porsche 911. i.e.: not going to happen.

Comment: _" I need more than 70ma"_ - how _much_ more than 70mA? Or do you just want _at least_ 70mA? _"The battery should have a capacity of at least 250ma/1.5V"_ - what do you mean by that (mA is current, not capacity). Exactly what battery do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two transistor same as q3 and q4 it worked. but it can improved with change some  parameter!

[image: 5V Output, 1.5V input Switch Boost Converter]